# Getting a segmentation fault after reading in from a data file

Tags: c++, file, segmentation-fault

Having some trouble reading in from a data file that has 200,000 lines. New to coding!

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
std::fstream dataFile;
dataFile.open(std::string("/opt/local/share/Geant4/Data/Geant4.10.5/G4ENSDFSTATE2.2/ENSDFSTATE.dat"), std::ios::in); //open a file to perform read
G4String particleSubstring;
if(nucleonsFound == true)
{
    string line;
    string lifetime;
    string nospaceline;
    double halflife;

    particleSubstring = to_string(numProtons) + to_string(nucleonsNum) + excitationEnergy + "-";

    while(getline(dataFile, line)){
    
        nospaceline = line.substr(0, 29);
        nospaceline.erase(remove(nospaceline.begin(), nospaceline.end(), ' '), nospaceline.end());

        if (nospaceline.find(particleSubstring) == 0) {
        
            cout << "ParticleInfo: " << line << endl;
            lifetime = line.substr(33, 14);
        
            cout <<  "Particle Lifetime:" << lifetime <<  "ns" << endl;
        
            halflife = stod (lifetime)*log(2);
            cout<< "Paricle Half-Life "<< halflife <<" ns"<<endl;
        
        }
        
    }
    
}
dataFile.close();
```

And the data file I am reading in from has the following format:

```
118  294               0  -     123456789101    0                 0
```

I know this is not the best way to be reading in appropriate values, but it gives me the value I seek, but then it segfaults at the last line of the file.

Comment: On which line does it crash?

Comment: It crashes on the very last line of the data file, when I "cout << line" it gets to the final line of actual numbers and then segfaults.